# How to use /testfor to sense mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a map I'm making, there are skeletons that you have to shoot, kind of like a carnival game. But I want one to spawn only when there are none there, so they all don't pile up. Is there a way I can use `/testfor` to do this?

Comment: Why not use pressure plates?

Comment: wow... I feel so stupid for not thinking of that. I guess I just thought of doing it with command blocks rather than anything else so I wasn't considering the options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While DominatorX's solution is perfectly valid - the command you are looking for might look something like this:

```
/testfor @e[type=Mobtype*,x=x,y=y,z=z,r=r**]
```

*`Mobtype` would be replaced with the mob you are looking for, like `Skeleton` will search for skellies, and `Zombie` will search for zombies. Alternatively, if you don't need to specify the type of mob, you can remove the `[type=Mobtype]` all together. This will just search for any entity.

**this can be used to specify a specific location, and a radius around that location. Alternatively, you can just use `r=r` and it will test within the point of origin (the command block)

Comment: This may or may not be a stupid question, but are the *'s supposed to be in the actual command or was it just being used to explain?

Comment: @xXPikminXx yes they were just being used to explain haha. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Mob types are Capitalized and Minecraft cares about that.

Answer (score 2):

USE PRESSURE PLATES!

You're really overthinking the problem.

Comment: Yep. I really was. like I said, I was thinking of using command blocks and not considering the options..

Comment: Yep, it's a thing among programmers too.  Which is why my computer science teacher sorta dislikes <s>me</s> my style cuz I use too many objects :)

Comment: Spot the programmer :P

Comment: Quote Henry Ford: "If you have a difficult problem, find a l̶a̶z̶y̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶s̶o̶n̶  programmer and they will find an easier way to do it."